# How to plot contour maps and display average of the mark(associated with x,y) for each contour level

Tags: owin, contour, spatstat

I have a contour map in spatstat generated from the intensity function of a point pattern X (like "location of the trees"). Each x,y coordinates in this point pattern is marked with a corresponding third vector (like "diameter of the tree").
-->cf image (of course the vertical lines representing the tree can be omitted)

I would like to display the average of the mark (diameter) in each level of the contour with different colors. Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is bit vague and I don't know exactly what you want. Could you please supply an example with code of what you have done so far? Possibly use a built-in dataset as an example (e.g. `spruces` which has locations and numeric marks with sizes of trees).

Comment: After reading you post again I think I understand it better: You want to extract the spatial regions defined by the contours; extract the trees in each of these regions and calculate their mean size; make a filled contour plot with colour corresponding to the mean size. If that is right I think the answer is that there is no easy way to do this. What do you need the plot for? Could you use the `weights` argument of `density.ppp` to obtain a plot (possibly in combination with other plots) that conveys the information you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively asking for a kind of nonparametric regression.

Here is a quick-and-dirty calculation using the function `rhohat` and demonstrated on the `longleaf` dataset.

First calculate the intensity estimate: `Z <- density(longleaf)` yielding an image `Z`. Next treat `Z` as a covariate in calls to the `rhohat` command:

`f <- rhohat(unmark(longleaf), Z)`

and

`g <- rhohat(unmark(longleaf), Z, weights=marks(longleaf))`.

Now take the ratio, `h <- eval.fv(g/f)` and plot it, `plot(h)`. This shows the estimated average tree diameter as a function of the forest density. To apply this function h to the original contours of Z you would first convert `h` to a true function by `H <- as.function(h)` then evaluate `hZ <- eval.im(H(Z))` and finally `plot(hZ)`.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, it works (not that I had any doubts since the answer was coming from you...). Looking forward for the spatstat book by the way!